# Visualize Lua variables

Tags: lua

I would like to display all the variables of Lua code using some debugger functions, but i can't get the exacte size of the tables, and also i can't retrieve the element of some tables (value, name, etc).

The following code illustrate what i did :

```
local name, value;
local NIL = {} -- to represent nil variables
local locals = {}
local a = 9
local i = 1
local tab ={1,2,3,4,4,4}
local tab2 = {22,22,22,22}
local tab4 = {'X', 'Y','Z'}

while( true ) do
    name, value = debug.getlocal( 1, i )
    if ( name == nil ) then break end
    locals[ name ] = value == nil and NIL or value
    i = i + 1
end

for k, v in pairs( locals ) do
  if(type(v) ~= "table") then -- if it's a simple variable
      print( k, v )
  else 
    print("tabel : "..k) -- if it's a table, display it's element 
    print("size : "..#k)
    -- I want to diplay all the elements of the table !! 
    for x, y in pairs(v) do
      print(y)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The "size" operator `#table` only works for array-like tables.

Comment: please read [3.4.7 – The Length Operator](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7) referring to Lua's reference manual should always be the first thing you do...

Comment: Definitely, you should read about the [environment](https://www.lua.org/pil/14.html)  and  [The Debug Library](https://www.lua.org/pil/23.html).

Comment: Some alternatives to rolling your own: If you can run your program in an IDE, check out the list in the [Lua tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lua/info). If you can only run a portion of your code in an IDE, try [unit testing](https://www.google.com/search?q=lua+unit+testing&oq=lua+unit+testing&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.3919j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [inspect](https://github.com/kikito/inspect.lua) library (useful to print nested tables) or [print_r](https://github.com/robmiracle/print_r) function